# # Buildozer failed to execute the last command # python kivy

Tags: python, kivy

Can anyone please resolve my issue I am using buildozer on google colab to convert a .py file to apk for my android mobile

This is the short code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.clock import Clock

import bluetooth
import threading

class BluetoothApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.layout = GridLayout(cols=1)
        
        self.output_label = Label(text="Connect Bluetooth")
        self.layout.add_widget(self.output_label)

        self.input_text = TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.layout.add_widget(self.input_text)

        self.connect_button = Button(text="Connect Bluetooth")
        self.connect_button.bind(on_press=self.connect_bluetooth)
        self.layout.add_widget(self.connect_button)

        self.send_button = Button(text="Send Data")
        self.send_button.bind(on_press=self.send_data)
        self.layout.add_widget(self.send_button)

        self.receive_button = Button(text="Receive Data")
        self.receive_button.bind(on_press=self.receive_data)
        self.layout.add_widget(self.receive_button)

        return self.layout



if __name__ == "__main__":
    BluetoothApp().run()
```

When I use buildozer android debug it returns me this error:

```
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

Could you help me.!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: # Command failed: ['/usr/bin/python3', '-m', 'pythonforandroid.toolchain', 'create', '--dist_name=myapp', '--bootstrap=sdl2', '--requirements=python3==3.8.3,hostpython==3.8.3,kivy==2.1.0,kivymd==0.104.2,pybluez-master', '--arch=arm64-v8a', '--arch=armeabi-v7a', '--copy-libs', '--color=always', '--storage-dir=/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a', '--ndk-api=21', '--ignore-setup-py', '--debug']